# Передача значений переменных между методами

Tags: java

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    readText();
    rectangle();
}

public static void readText() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int m = Integer.parseInt(read.readLine());
    int n = Integer.parseInt(read.readLine());
}

public static void rectangle(){

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.print(8);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

метод rectangle() не видит значений переменных "m" и "n", которые вводятся в методе readText(), как исправить?

Comment: Пришло время почитать про области видимости переменных в Java

Comment: Я понимаю что "m" и "n" - локальные переменные, что они видны в пределах метода readText(). Я спрашиваю как исходя из этого сделать рабочий код?

Comment: очевидно, что вынести их в поле класса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Solution {
    int static n;
    int static m;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    readText();
    rectangle();
}

public static void readText() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    m = Integer.parseInt(read.readLine());
    n = Integer.parseInt(read.readLine());
}

public static void rectangle(){

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.print(8);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Но лучше всего было бы создать экземляр класса Solution и у него вызывать методы, чтобы static было меньше

Comment: А можете как раз эту часть кода написать? Пожалуйста
"Но лучше всего было бы создать экземляр класса Solution и у него вызывать методы" 
Как это написать?

Comment: Не задавайте такие вопросы, если учите JAva. Вам дали подсказок куда больше, чем нужно, даже новичку. Разбирайтесь.